# NoClassDefFoundError when calling function from RESTful web service

Tags: rest, jax-rs, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to create a RESTful web service in java that will allow authentication with a Yubikey.
I'm modifying an existing tutorial that I completed while trying to learn about REST.

I'm trying to call the validation function from within the javax.ws.rs.core.Response function but keep getting an error with a package from the imported yubikey jars.

I imported these jars from build path -> libraries --> Add external Jars

Error as follows when I post my form to the RESTful url:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yubico/client/v2/exceptions/YubicoValidationException**

```
package de.vogella.jersey.todo.resources;


import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.yubico.client.v2.exceptions.YubicoValidationException;
import com.yubico.client.v2.exceptions.YubicoValidationFailure;
import de.vogella.jersey.todo.resources.Validate;

@Path("/test")
public class Test {

@POST
public Response testCred(@FormParam("username") String username,
          @FormParam("password") String password,
          @FormParam("otp") String otp) throws YubicoValidationException, YubicoValidationFailure {
    int client_id = 11095; 
    boolean status;
    status = Validate.validate(otp, client_id);

    return Response.status(200)
        .entity("validation status: : " + status + ", for client " + otp)
        .build();

    }

}
```

the validate class is as follows:

```
package de.vogella.jersey.todo.resources;

import com.yubico.client.v2.YubicoClient;
import com.yubico.client.v2.YubicoResponse;
import com.yubico.client.v2.YubicoResponseStatus;
import com.yubico.client.v2.exceptions.YubicoValidationException;
import com.yubico.client.v2.exceptions.YubicoValidationFailure;


public class Validate {

 public static boolean validate(String otp, int client_id) throws YubicoValidationException, YubicoValidationFailure {
        YubicoClient client = YubicoClient.getClient(client_id);
        YubicoResponse response = client.verify(otp);
        if(response != null && response.getStatus() == YubicoResponseStatus.OK) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
     }

}
```

Comment: You need to include the Yubico JAR's in your deployed web app. For better help, add the full stacktrace to your question, as well as what app server you are using and how you build your app.

Comment: How do I include the Yubico JAR's in my deployed web app?

Comment: Theres a thousand answers to that question - how are you building your WAR?

Comment: I'm new to java so bear with me here, I create a dynamic web project in eclipse, import my jars to build path library, set up my web.xml, put together a package or two with some class files and then rightclick on the project in explorer view and run as -> on server, this runs it on a tomcat server on my localhost.

Comment: For Dynamic Web Projects, drop the JAR's you need into the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Thanks man, your a legend, I've been stuck on this for 2 days now. If you're ever in Ireland look me up and I'll buy you a couple of pints.